# warning: Parse Issue: Use of GNU old-style field designator extension

Tags: iphone, ios, warnings, coordinates, gnu

I tried the following code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 61.2180556, longitude: -149.9002778};
```

and the compiler was showing the following warning

```
warning: Parse Issue: Use of GNU old-style field designator extension
```

Can somebody help me to understand what the complier is trying to say?

Comment: C99 defined a syntax for this, so GCC's old syntax was deprecated. See @booiljoung's answer for the C99-standard syntax.

Comment: why didn't you post the comment as answer. Thats the answer to my question. thanks anyways.

Comment: Because @booiljuong already gave you the replacement syntax.

Comment: I was not worried about how to resolve the warning, that xcode already suggested me. my aim was to the the reason of warning.

Comment: Was quite difficult for me to find information about this. I'm using g++ and started using this JSON-like syntax by accident. The compiler didn't complain. At some point I noticed people on the web always use the `{.prop = value}` syntax and started wondering. I ended up trying different compilers using a web compiler explorer and clang reported this useful warning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  61.2180556, .longitude = -149.9002778};
```

Comment: i was not worried about how to resolve the warning. I aksed the question to understand the reason of warning. So @jonathan did. Anyways thanks a lot.